# how to use zbar sdk in universal application(iphone and ipad)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, frameworks, barcode-scanner, universal

I am creating the universal application(iPhone and iPad). In my application, i used ZBar SDK for barcode scanning. While running the application in iPhone it's working fine. But in iPad the application is not opening. In console it shows the error,

> dyld: Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /ios 4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Please refer me is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you read your error message closely, it says it expected to find a symbol (`_CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr`) in a particular framework (Security.framework). Did you add this framework to your project properly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these system frameworks to your project:

- AVFoundation.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- CoreVideo.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- libiconv.dylib